# Connecting to crypto wallet from a mobile app

Tags: mobile-wallet, walletconnect

I am building a mobile app with react native and I am having users register by connecting to a crypto wallet (like Opensea or Rarible do). Only things I have seen online use a QRcode as a private key which is scanned by crypto wallet. Problem is that, since they are already on their phone they can't scan the qrcode on the same device. Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

WalletConnect supports [mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking). It allows an application and a wallet on the same phone discuss over WalletConnect link.